# endDate should not be equal to startDate

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

This is already working and validating `endDate` could not be lesser than the `startDate`. My question is how can I validate the `endDate` field not to be equal to `startDate`

Ex. if `startDate` is selected at **2020-2-27**, the `endDate` field could not select the **2020-2-27**. The starting date should be **2020-2-28**.

This is what I tried

```
   Start Date: <input type="text" id="startDate">
   End Date: <input type="text" id="endDate">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<script>
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date(new Date().setYear(start.getFullYear()+1));

$('#startDate').datepicker({
    endDate   : end
}).on('changeDate', function(){
    $('#endDate').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date($(this).val()));
}); 
$('#endDate').datepicker({
    startDate : start,
    endDate   : end
}).on('changeDate', function(){
    $('#startDate').datepicker('setEndDate', new Date($(this).val()));
});
</script>
```